# How are import packages resolved in Android Studio and how to replace a package

Tags: java, android, import

I have import

```
com.mycompany.projectgroup.projectName.connectionService;
```

in my MainActivity.
connectionService itself has

```
import static com.mycompany.projectgroup.projectName.connections.connectionName.connectionCommands.DEFAULT;
```

Am I right that Android Studio 2.1 with Gradle now looks for the packages in any of the dependencies in build.gradle?

```
    dependencies 
    {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.mycompany:projectgroup.projectName:beta6-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```

How does it know whether to find it local or in an online repository?

How can I force Android Studio to use a local version for one single class

```
import static com.mycompany.projectgroup.projectName.connections.connectionName.connectionCommands.DEFAULT;
```

but the online version for all other classes?

Comment: Java doesn't import anything from online. All dependencies are downloaded locally.

Comment: So it downloads everything mentioned in `repositories{ maven { url '...'}}` and then searches the local copy for the items in `dependencies{ compile '...'}}`?

Comment: It downloads the things mentioned by `compile` by searching the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/), or whatever repositories you have set

Comment: Okay, thank you.
So how could I replace a downloaded file with a modified local copy? I tried to simply create the file `app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/projectgroup/projectName/connections/connectionName/connectionCommands` with my modified `public static final String DEFAULT`, but then I get _AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files..._ I guess I need to tell gradle which one to use?

Comment: Well, that error means you have compiled something twice, and it not related to replacing a downloaded file. I would suggest you use the `lib/` folder instead of Maven dependencies if you are going to be changing some code constantly. Only use the Maven version when you have a stable release.

Comment: So download the source code of the library, place it in `lib/` and replace the file there? And to answer the question, there is no way to force Android Studio to replace a single classfile of an external library with a modified local copy?

Comment: You would replace a JAR file in the `lib/` folder of the compiled source code. There is not a way to change one single classfile unless you are compiling that library's source as a separate module within the application.